# What's a more pythonic way to build this simple factory class?

Tags: python, paramiko

**Preface:**  I'm very new to Python.  I usually write PHP.  I also know this might be considered a subjective question and it might be marked as such, but I do think an answer could emerge from this that is "correct enough" and it would certainly help me.  Also I don't know where else to ask.

Right now, this is just play-code, but the idea I was playing with was to have some sort of static factory that builds a Paramiko SSHClient class based on options.  I'm not sure how I'll design this ultimately, but I have a strong feeling that even now I'm not taking full advantage of python design features, and instead forcing it to work like PHP.  Basically, Am I *doing it wrong* already?

```
import paramiko
import time
import sys

class Client:

    @staticmethod
    def build(host, **options):

        default_connect_opts = {'look_for_keys': True}
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()

        # automatically add untrusted hosts
        if options.get('special').get('auto_add_policy'):
            client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

        our_connect_opts = options.get('connect');

        # merge defaults with provided with preference for provided opts
        connect_opts = dict(default_connect_opts.items() + our_connect_opts.items())
        #print connect_opts
        #sys.exit()

        client.connect(host, **connect_opts)
        return client

options = {
    'connect': {
        'username': 'root',
        'password': 'p4assw0rd',
        'look_for_keys': False,
    },
    'special': {
        'auto_add_policy': True,
    }
}
client = Client.build('10.0.0.13', **options)
print client
```

**Edit:** Just for clarity on what I'm trying to accomplish ultimately -- I will probably want to build paramiko sshclients for generic unix / linux hosts, but also want to be able to build specialized sshclient classes for oddballs like a Cisco switch that doesn't run a *real* shell.  And to do that I have to pass additional options to disable paging, and sometimes `sleep` between commands, etc, depending on the nature of the remote "shell".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware of `NoneType Error`.
`options.get('special').get('auto_add_policy')` will throw exception when `special` not in `options` cauz you can't do `None.get()`.

```
    # Deal with `options` without key 'special'
    if options.get('special', {}).get('auto_add_policy'):
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    default_connect_opts.update(options.get('connect', {}))

    client.connect(host, **default_connect_opts)
```

You can derive `SSHClient` in your purpose, and get rid of `default_connect_opts` for `look_for_key = True` by default.

```
class Client(paramiko.SSHClient):

    def __init__(self, host, **options):
        super(Client, self).__init__()
        # set policy
        if options.get('special', {}).get('auto_add_policy'):
            self._policy = paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()
        # look_for_key = True by default
        self.connect(host, **options.get('connect', {}))

client = Client(host, **options)
new_client = Client(new_host, **new_options)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was wondering about that.  Also I didn't know about `update()` -- that seems cleaner at first glance.